# Can i have special characters in a data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data

I have this name in data extension with accent but it is not showing up correctly.

José

The é shows up as Jos� in data extension and when i display it in email, same issue.

So my question is if data extension support accents. If yes, is there a special way to import accents?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted so others can see this has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the correct encoding when importing/writing to your data extension and also for your email the accent works without an issue.

Using UTF-8 is usually a good idea (depending on the countries you send the emails to), so check if this is correctly set. For further information check the [System Guide about International Sends](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/system_guides/international_sends/).

**Encoding for the Import:**

> File Encoding - Select the type of file encoding you want to use. If no type is selected, the system defaults to UTF-8.
> (Source: [Import into a Data Extension](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/importing_into_a_data_extension/))

**Encoding for the Email:**

Depends on the way you send the email. When using Content Builder this can be done in the Properties of your email via the "Target Language" setting where you can select "Unicode - UTF-8" in the select-box.

> The language field sets the content-type value in the email header. This field determines how an email will be displayed, especially with special characters. We recommend using UTF-8 Unicode. When creating content with specific characters set, select the corresponding option from the drop-down. Changing the language option does not update the meta tag in the HTML.
> (Source: Tooltip/Helptext in Content Builder Preferences)

**Additional information:**

- [System Guide: International File Encoding](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/system_guides/international_file_encoding/)
- [System Guide: International Sends](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/system_guides/international_sends/)
- [Import into a Data Extension](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/importing_into_a_data_extension/)

Comment: During the import, I do not see any encoding option. I am importing it as CSV file. By import, I mean while importing data to data extension.

Comment: You need to make sure the CSV-file is encoded as UTF-8 then.